# NodeJS: Using npm package casperjs

Tags: node.js, casperjs

I have installed casperjs npm module in nodejs. Also installed phantomjs npm package before casperjs.
Installed using "**npm install casperjs --save**"
But got an exception "**Cannot find module casper**"

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
```

Comment: can you find it in `node_modules` folder?

Comment: @Cr. Yes it is present in node_modules.

Answer (score 3):

You simply **cannot** use CasperJS in NodeJS.

Quote from official docs:

> While CasperJS is installable via npm, it is not a NodeJS module and
>   will not work with NodeJS out of the box. You cannot load casper by
>   using require(‘casperjs’) in node. Note that CasperJS is not capable
>   of using a vast majority of NodeJS modules out there.

For more details read this links from official documentation:

[Installing from npm](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-from-npm)

[Is CasperJS a node.js library?](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/faq.html#is-casperjs-a-node-js-library)